# Easiest and Fastest way to Embed a Python Script into C?

Tags: python, python-c-api, python-embedding

I have been looking at the Python/C API for embedding my python script into C.  I want to know if there is an easy (or simpler) way to embed my python script without having to get too involved in the python/c API. 
I should mention (cause I am not sure if this will be a problem) that in my python script I am using a number of other modules in my python script (NumPy, SciPy, Matplotlib and Mayavi to be exact).
Any help or advice you might be able to give would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, embedding Python is surprisingly easy: http://docs.python.org/2/extending/embedding.html#very-high-level-embedding

Comment: I thought Cython was for writing C extensions for Python, which if I am not mistaken is the opposite of embedding.  Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @user1750948: Quoting from the About page: "This makes Cython the ideal language for wrapping external C libraries, **embedding CPython into existing applications**, and for fast C modules that speed up the execution of Python code."

Comment: `cython` because ultimately it is also generating `c` equivalent code.. .without too much focus on `c` and just doing everything in pythonic way!

Comment: Yes you guys are correct.  It appears that Cython can be used for embedding according to this page: http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/external_C_code.html.

Comment: I know this a an old thread, but I figured I would give this a shot.  I was wondering if it is possible to create a DLL from the cython code